# Not able to scan 2d barcode

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I developed barcodescanner application in phonegap android.I am able to scan qrcode and barcode. But I am unable to scan [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=2d%20barcode&biw=1517&bih=741&tbm=isch&imgil=E3yasFJ__UEn8M%253A%253BhIy_tWeEkirPlM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.fakeidtrainers.com%25252Fid-scanners%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=E3yasFJ__UEn8M%253A%252ChIy_tWeEkirPlM%252C_&usg=__svTPW0QsYFlJ0yUVCC5Pu2m4nCI%3D&dpr=0.9&ved=0CDUQyjc&ei=XFWRVM-BJc-WuATHnYCYDQ#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=E3yasFJ__UEn8M%253A%3BhIy_tWeEkirPlM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.fakeidtrainers.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2013%252F06%252F2D-bar-code.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.fakeidtrainers.com%252Fid-scanners%252F%3B1638%3B414) 2d barcode. Is it my fault or the code fault?

```
function scanCode(){

    var scanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner"); 

    scanner.scan(
             function(result){
                 alert("Scanned Code: " + result.text 
                 + ". Format: " + result.format
                 + ". Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);

             }, 

             function(error){
                 alert("Scan failed: " + error);
             }
         );
    }

function encodeData(){
    var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
    if (data != ''){
        cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.encode(
            BarcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE, data, 
            function(success){
                alert("Encode success: " + success);
            }, 

            function(fail){
                alert("Encoding failed: " + fail);
            }
        );
    }

    else{
        alert("Please enter some data.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you should add some code to let others see and find out whose fault it is.

Comment: Could you be more precise which 2D barcode are you trying to scan as 2D is a general name and not a specific standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a PDF417 barcode. It looks like the BarcodeScanner plugin has problems with that format. Try another plugin, like this one:

https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-phonegap

Comment: can you tell me where I can get mobi.pdf417.Pdf417MobiSettings;     import mobi.pdf417.Pdf417MobiScanData;
import mobi.pdf417.activity.Pdf417ScanActivity;
import net.photopay.barcode.BarcodeDetailedData;
import net.photopay.hardware.camera.CameraType; where I can get these imports

Comment: You might want to contact them or get more info at their website. Be aware it is only free for non-commercial use: http://pdf417.mobi/

Comment: is there any possibility to make it possible in phonegap?  or only possibility is there in native android?

Comment: Mentioned link provides Phonegap plugin and demo application using the plugin. The imports you listed are part of the plugin. If needed PDF417 plugin is also available as native iOS/Android library.

Comment: @ssasa I added this Pdf417Demo from https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-phonegap/tree/master/Pdf417Demo .so I am getting 'Uncaught ReferenceError: scanWithCustomUIButton is not defined' error. can you please tell me why I am getting this error

Comment: @Prathyusha hi, please checkout new version and rebuild demo app, customUIButton was incorrectly removed from the demo app